# Populate column based on row values BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a Table lets say :-

```
  Name   A    B    C    D    
------- ---  ---  ---  --- 
 alpha   0    1    0   0.6     
 beta   0.6   0    0   0.1
 gama    0    0    0   0.6
```

Now I want to populate values on Two columns`(Result & Class)` based on A, B, C, D values.

The condition is if value in any of the field(A,B,C,D) is >.5 then `Result` column should have "F" else it should have "P". Also the column whose valie is >.5 should be in `Class` example("A,D")

For better understanding here is the result I want:-

```
  Name   A    B    C    D    Result    Class
------- ---  ---  ---  ---  --------  -------
 alpha   0    1    0   0.6     F        B,D      
 beta   0.6   0    0   0.1     F         A
 gama    0    0    0   0.4     P        NULL
```

I am New to BigQuery and need Help. What would be workaround.

This what I have done till yet

```
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN (A > .5 OR B > .5 OR C > .5 OR D >.5)
            THEN 'F'
            ELSE 'P' END AS Result AND Class....//here i am stuck
  
  FROM table1
```

Actually, I have no Idea how to Build this exact Script. I was able to achieve first part where I was able to Populate Result column with "F" and "P" but could not make Class to populate column names....

Comment: Hope My question is pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are analysing each column, I assume you do not have a extensive quantity of columns. Therefore, I created a simple [JavaScript User Defined Function (UDF)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure) in order to check the row's value and return the column's name if the condition is met.

I have used the provided sample data to test the below query.

```
#javaScript UDF
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION class(A FLOAT64, B FLOAT64, C FLOAT64, D FLOAT64)
RETURNS String
LANGUAGE js AS """
var class_array=[];
if(A > 0.5){class_array.push("A");}
if(B > 0.5){class_array.push("B");}
if(C > 0.5){class_array.push("C");}
if(D > 0.5){class_array.push("D");} 

return class_array;
""";

#sample data
WITH data as (
 SELECT "alpha" as Name, 0 as A, 1 as B, 0 as C, 0.6 as D UNION ALL  
 SELECT "beta", 0.6, 0, 0, 0.1 UNION ALL
 SELECT "gama", 0, 0, 0, 0.4
)

Select name, A,B,C,D, 
        CASE WHEN (A > .5 OR B > .5 OR C > .5 OR D >.5) THEN "F" ELSE "P" END AS Result,
        IF(class(A,B,C,D) is null , null, class(A,B,C,D)) as Class from data
```

And the output,

```
Row name    A   B   C   D   Result  Class
1   alpha   0   1   0   0.6 F       B,D
2   beta    0.6 0   0   0.1 F       A
3   gama    0   0   0   0.4 P
```

As it is shown within the UDF, each row's value is analysed and if the condition is met, the column's name is **manually** added to an array of strings. In addition, pay attention that the JS UDF returns a String, not an array. It automatically converts the previously created Array to String.

*Lastly, I should point that is not possible to retrieve the column name within a query in this context. Although, you can retrieve it, in other scenarios, using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables).*

Comment: I would have around 5500 rows max hope this would not timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Using javaScript UDF helps in many cases but should be avoid if problem can be solved with SQL as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  ( SELECT IF(LOGICAL_OR(val > 0.5), 'F', 'P') 
    FROM UNNEST([A,B,C,D]) val
  ) AS Result,
  ( SELECT STRING_AGG(['A','B','C','D'][OFFSET(pos)]) 
    FROM UNNEST([A,B,C,D]) val WITH OFFSET pos 
    WHERE val > 0.5
  ) AS Class
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test , play with above using sample data from y our question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'alpha' name, 0 A, 1 B, 0 C, 0.6 D UNION ALL
  SELECT 'beta', 0.6, 0, 0, 0.1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'gamma', 0, 0, 0, 0.4 
)
SELECT *,
  ( SELECT IF(LOGICAL_OR(val > 0.5), 'F', 'P') 
    FROM UNNEST([A,B,C,D]) val
  ) AS Result,
  ( SELECT STRING_AGG(['A','B','C','D'][OFFSET(pos)]) 
    FROM UNNEST([A,B,C,D]) val WITH OFFSET pos 
    WHERE val > 0.5
  ) AS Class
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output as

```
Row name    A       B   C   D       Result  Class    
1   alpha   0.0     1   0   0.6     F       B,D  
2   beta    0.6     0   0   0.1     F       A    
3   gamma   0.0     0   0   0.4     P       null
```